# Unexpected types from UINT32_C, UINTN_C

Tags: c, language-lawyer

> **7.20.4.1 Macros for minimum-width integer constants**
>   ... The macro `UINTN_C(value)` shall expand to an integer constant expression corresponding to the type `uint_leastN_t`. For example, if `uint_least64_t` is a name for the type `unsigned long long int`, then `UINT64_C(0x123`) might expand to the integer constant `0x123ULL`.  C11dr §7.20.4.1 1

The type of `UINTN_C()` and friends are not as expected.  See "Expected" comments in code output.

A) Is my compiler implementation wrong and the constant type should be `uint_leastN_t`?
or
B) Should the type of constant from `UINTN_C(value)` be the minimum of `uint_leastN_t`, `int`, `unsigned` and type needed to encode the value?
or
C) something else?

---

I had expected that the type of the constants to correspond to `uint_leastN_t`, but it appears to not be so under 2 conditions:

**1 If the macro corresponding type is below `int/unsigned`, the constant is `int/unsigned`

**2 If the value exceeds the range of the `uint_leastN_t`, then the type becomes a wider type constant.

> §6.4.4.1 "The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented ... (long list follows).

---

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define type_of(X) _Generic((X), \
  unsigned long long: "unsigned long long", \
  unsigned long: "unsigned long", \
  unsigned: "unsigned", \
  int: "int", \
  unsigned short: "unsigned short", \
  default: "?" \
  )

int main() {
  uint_least16_t u16 = 0;
  uint_least32_t u32 = 0;
  uint_least64_t u64 = 0;
  printf("%zu %s\n", sizeof(u16), type_of(u16));
  printf("%zu %s\n", sizeof(u32), type_of(u32));
  printf("%zu %s\n", sizeof(u64), type_of(u64));
  puts("");
  printf("%zu %s\n", sizeof((uint_least16_t) UINT16_C(0)), type_of((uint_least16_t) UINT16_C(0)));
  printf("%zu %s\n", sizeof UINT16_C(0), type_of(UINT16_C(0)));
  printf("%zu %s\n", sizeof UINT16_C(0x1234), type_of(UINT16_C(0x1234)));
  printf("%zu %s\n", sizeof UINT16_C(0x12345), type_of(UINT16_C(0x12345)));
  printf("%zu %s\n", sizeof UINT32_C(0x12345678), type_of(UINT32_C(0x12345678)));
  printf("%zu %s\n", sizeof UINT32_C(0x123456789), type_of(UINT32_C(0x123456789)));
  return 0;

  //round_frac_test(-2.05446162500000000e+06, 205);
  round_frac_test(fp_rand(), 6);
  round_frac_tests(10000);
  puts("Done");
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
2 unsigned short
4 unsigned
8 unsigned long long

2 unsigned short
4 int       // Expected 2 unsigned short, see **1
4 int       // Expected 2 unsigned short, see **1
4 int       // Expected 2 unsigned short, see **2
4 unsigned
8 unsigned long long  // Expected 4 unsigned, see **2
```

I am using (GNU C11 (GCC) version 5.4.0)

In forming this post, I am leaning toward B, yet I am looking for your rational for confirmation -one way of the other.   If B is so, a disappointing part is that `UINTN_C()` could result in a *signed* type.

I suppose that is what the "minimum-width" part is about.

Comment: I think you have a very valid point. The glibc macros in `stdint.h` should be e.g. `#define UINT16_C(c) ((uint16_t)(c))` and so on, whereas right now they are just `#define UINT16_C(c) c` (or `c # U`, `c # UL`, `c # ULL` for larger types). Care to file a [bug report](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/FilingBugs)? It usually only takes about a year for a tested patch to be accepted, and another year or so to dribble down to Linux distributions, in my experience.

Comment: Could this hinge on the _corresponding_ in "shall expand to an integer constant expression _corresponding_ to the type `uint_leastN_t`." In [§6.2.5 6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p6) there is "For each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but different) unsigned integer type"; that is, maybe a type corresponding to an unsigned integer type need not be unsigned?

Comment: MSVC isn't much better: `#define UINT16_C(x)  (x)`

Comment: @dbush It is intentional

Comment: @NominalAnimal No, that wouldn't be valid, because that wouldn't work in `#if` expressions.

Comment: @hvd: Good point. That, and [Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45467680/1475978)'s answer below shows my original reaction was incorrect. (As usual...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is covered in the parent subsection, 7.20.4.

In the portion you quoted:

> The macro `UINTN_C(value)` shall expand to an integer constant expression corresponding to the type `uint_leastN_t`.

it says "*corresponding to*", not that the expansion is actually *of* that type.  The meaning of "*corresponding to*" is explained in 7.20.4p3:

> Each invocation of one of these macros shall expand to an integer
>   constant expression suitable for use in **`#if`** preprocessing directives.
>   The type of the expression shall have the same type as would an
>   expression of the corresponding type converted according to the
>   integer promotions. The value of the expression shall be that of the
>   argument.

Since the macros are intended to be used in an `#if` directive, they cannot use casts (the preprocessor doesn't understand casts or type names).

In practice, such a constant expression will almost always be implicitly converted to the appropriate type, so the fact that its actual type differs from what you might expect is not generally a problem.

As for a value outside the range of `uint_leastN_t`, that's also covered in the parent subsection, in 7.20.4p2:

> The argument in any instance of these macros shall be an unsuffixed
>   integer constant (as defined in 6.4.4.1) with a value that does not
>   exceed the limits for the corresponding type.

This is a "shall" outside a constraint, so violating it causes undefined behavior.  Don't do that.

(When reading the C standard, it's generally a good idea to check the parent subsections for wording that might clarify or override what you're reading. I've been bitten by this myself.)

Comment: The "The type of the expression shall have the same type as would an expression of the corresponding type converted according to the integer promotions. " certainly explains the "**1" of the question.

Comment: ... and 7.20.4p2: explains "**2".  Hmmm " check the parent" sounds like advice of years ago.

Answer (score 0):

On the host with 16 bit `short` and 32 bit integers `unsigned short` numbers are promoted to `int`. So the those macros are defined as:

```
#define INT16_C(x) (x)
#define UINT16_C(x) (x)
```

with no 'U' suffix for the `unsigned short`

> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
>   by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int;

Those macros do only expand to the corresponding constants (or integer literals using more common language), and do not create any objects, and have to usable in the #if. So no casts are allowed. Macros do not perform any range checks as well.

```
int16_t x0 = 123;
uint16_t x1 = 123;    // no sign suffix needed
int32_t x2 = 2147483647;
uint32_t x3 = 2147583647U;  //sign suffix theoreticaly needed as int and unsigned int have the same rank
int64_t x4 = 9223372036854775807LL; 
uint64_t x5 = 9237372036854775807ULL; //same as above
```

Comment: Where is your quote from? I’m surprised that conversion happens for constants.

Comment: 'Each invocation of one of these macros shall expand to an integer constant expression suitable for use in #if preprocessing directives. The type of the expression shall have the same type as would an expression of the corresponding type **converted according to the integer promotions**. The value of the expression shall be that of the argument.' And then it is from the integer promotion rules. I hope that is enough

Comment: Yeah, that’s the relevant part I was missing.